# CheckListBox for each

Tags: c#, checkbox

I'm losing my mind with `CheckListBox`, I tried to get all of my checked items in my list. Here the code I use, with the button which are on my User interface:

```
 public partial class formPCRBaseline : Form
{
    public formPCRBaseline(List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objPCRCheck)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setDefaults(m_objPCRCheck);

    }

    private void setDefaults(List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objPCRCheck)
    {
        checkedListBox.BackColor = Color.White;
        List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objCheckeditem = new List<GetBaselineSectionTasks>();
        int i= 0;
        foreach (GetBaselineSectionTasks i_objPCRCheck in m_objPCRCheck)
        {
            checkedListBox.Items.Add(i_objPCRCheck.taskname);



        }

    }

    private void buttonConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();

    }
    private void buttonClose_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }

    public List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> GetCheckedItems()
    {
        List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objCheckeditem = new List<GetBaselineSectionTasks>();
        m_objCheckeditem.AddRange(checkedListBox.CheckedItems.OfType<GetBaselineSectionTasks>());




        return m_objCheckeditem;
    }


}
}
```

And here the class I use to Initialize my component:

```
   private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.buttonClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.buttonConfirm = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.checkedListBox = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // buttonClose
        // 
        this.buttonClose.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.buttonClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F);
        this.buttonClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(306, 299);
        this.buttonClose.Name = "buttonClose";
        this.buttonClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.buttonClose.TabIndex = 0;
        this.buttonClose.Text = "Cancel";
        this.buttonClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonClose_Click_1);
        // 
        // buttonConfirm
        // 
        this.buttonConfirm.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.buttonConfirm.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8F);
        this.buttonConfirm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(192, 299);
        this.buttonConfirm.Name = "buttonConfirm";
        this.buttonConfirm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.buttonConfirm.TabIndex = 4;
        this.buttonConfirm.Text = "OK";
        this.buttonConfirm.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonConfirm.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonConfirm_Click);
        // 
        // checkedListBox
        // 
        this.checkedListBox.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.checkedListBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 5.5F);
        this.checkedListBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.checkedListBox.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl;
        this.checkedListBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 41);
        this.checkedListBox.Name = "checkedListBox";
        this.checkedListBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(394, 244);
        this.checkedListBox.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // formPCRBaseline
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(418, 334);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkedListBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonConfirm);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonClose);
        this.Name = "formPCRBaseline";
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        this.Text = "PMIS – Project Planning";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonClose;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonConfirm;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox checkedListBox;
```

But it doesn't work, when I use my *breakpoint*, it reached the `foreach`, I have *two selected items* but it doesn't *get in*
Any idea of what I could do?

Comment: A windows application

Comment: Did you try googling around how to access checked items from checklistbox? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-determine-checked-items-in-the-windows-forms-checkedlistbox-control

Comment: Yes but it's not working :/

Comment: Can you define `not working`?

Comment: `CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection`?

Comment: the document solution doesn't work because it returns me a null value
        for (int x = 0; x < checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count; x++)
            {
               
                m_objCheckeditem.Add(checkedListBox.CheckedItems[x] as GetBaselineSectionTasks);
            }
It returns me a null value, and I can convert this object to a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [CheckedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_CheckedListBox_CheckedItems) / [CheckedIndices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkedindices?view=netframework-4.7.2) property? Providing that `CheckListBox` - `checkedListBox` contains `GetBaselineSectionTasks` items, i.e. you fill it like this:

```
  checkedListBox.Items.Add(new GetBaselineSectionTasks(...));
  ... 
  checkedListBox.Items.Add(new GetBaselineSectionTasks(...));
```

You can put

```
  List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> m_objCheckeditem = new List<GetBaselineSectionTasks();

  ...
 m_objCheckeditem.AddRange(checkedListBox.CheckedItems.OfType<GetBaselineSectionTasks>());
```

or if you want to create a list in *one go*:

```
 List<GetBaselineSectionTasks> result = checkedListBox.CheckedItems
   .OfType<GetBaselineSectionTasks>()
   .ToList();
```

**Edit:** If are working with `string`s i.e. you fill `checkedListBox` like this:

```
 checkedListBox.Items.Add("Some Value");
 ... 
 checkedListBox.Items.Add("Some other value");
```

you can loop over checked items and when trying to foind out the corresponding

```
 foreach (int index in checkedListBox.CheckedIndices) {
   string taskName = Convert.ToString(checkedListBox[index]);

   // Now you have item index and item text (which is taskName). Let's try filling the list
   // We can try finding the item by string
   for (var item in m_objPCRCheck) {
     if (item.taskname == taskName) {
       m_objCheckeditem.Add(item);

       break; 
     } 
   }

   // Or (alternatively) you can trying to get index-th item:
   // m_objCheckeditem.Add(m_objPCRCheck[index]);
 }
```

Comment: It's not working, nothing is added in my list
It's weird because if I put a breakpoint I saw all the item I selected in my checkboxlist but the items are not added to my list

Comment: @Cookistador: what items are in the list? `String`s, `GetBaselineSectionTask` something else?

Comment: It's only  two strings 
A taskname and a taskID

Comment: @Cookistador: so you fill the `checkedListBox` as `checkedListBox.Add("SomeTaskName")`, right?

Comment: I edited my code to show you how I fill my checkedListbox

Comment: Are you creating `CheckBox`s *manually*? Not with a help of `Add`? `checkedListBox.Items.Add(...)`?

Comment: My checklist box has been created manually in the UI and my Checkboxlist.checkeditem returns me the right number of values that I checked

Comment: @Cookistador: Could you provide the code, please. It seems that you are doing in *quite unusual way*. Typically we create a control `checkedListBox = new CheckedListBox() {Location = ..., Size= ..., Parent = this};` and then add items: `checkedListBox.Items.Add(someObject);`

Comment: @Cookistador: I see; so you store `string` in the `checkedListBox`s items and you have to find out the corresponding `GetBaselineSectionTasks` instance from `m_objPCRCheck` in order to add into `m_objCheckeditem` list.

Comment: So I understand well what you mean, it's because of my .taskname?
Because I would like to display the name of my items, this is why I used the .taskname

Comment: @Cookistador: yes, a *better* way is to *override* `ToString()` in the `GetBaselineSectionTasks` class 
(for `CheckedListBox` to represnt items in desired way) and then add `GetBaselineSectionTasks` items. Having this done you'll be able to operate with items easily (my code before *Edit:*)